# Dual boot 32 bit and 64 bit Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, installation, multi-boot

I plan on leaving XP professional on my C drive...then installing Windows 7 professional on my D drive....therefore having a dual boot system...Can I install the Windows 7 as a 64 bit operating system to operate with the 32 bit XP that will remain on C?

Comment: Were you also looking for advice on how to go about doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your hardware supports a 64-bit operating system, you should be able to dual-boot to 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: One OS is not influenced by the other. They can both be installed on the same PC without any problems.

Comment: I'm currently running the reverse: XP x64 and Server 2008 x86. There a no problems with this configuration at all, except that I don't use XP anymore.